# A software for file(exe) binding

Tags: windows

Can you recommend a powerful file binder(joiner) for windows? I need to attach a program(exe) to a host program so they can run together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MFileBinder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfilebinder/).This program is capable of binding multiple file of any type

[image]

**Description of the FileBinder**

- mFileBinder is an advanced file binder which binds multiple file of
  any type and merges into a single executable file.
- mFileBinder uses rijndael encryption algorithm to encrypt the file
  which can make Virus / Trojans Fully Undetectable.
- Set the drop location of all files and set the execution
  mode(Background,Foreground) of each file.
- Predefined set of ICON Package is included set your desired icon.
  Silently extracts and sequentially execute files.

Source:[Description](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfilebinder/)